# Why does file loading takes huge time at first in GoLang ? and later it takes minimal time?

Tags: file, go, caching, memory-management

goProgram is simple utility which searches a file for a given string and results in true/false

when tried with data.log , it took around 160 ms first time, and later around 20 ms

```
I:\Study\GO> .\goProgram.exe I:\data.log "BUILD SUCCESS"
true
Execution time : 156.4336ms

I:\Study\GO> .\goProgram.exe I:\data.log "BUILD SUCCESS"
true
Execution time : 19.1512ms

I:\Study\GO> .\goProgram.exe I:\data.log "BUILD SUCCESS"
true
Execution time : 19.5516ms

I:\Study\GO> .\goProgram.exe I:\data.log "BUILD SUCCESS"
true
Execution time : 18.5528ms
```

when tried with data1.log , it took around 180 ms first time, and later around 20 ms

```
I:\Study\GO> .\goProgram.exe I:\data1.log "BUILD SUCCESS"
true
Execution time : 178.5104ms

I:\Study\GO> .\goProgram.exe I:\data1.log "BUILD SUCCESS"
true
Execution time : 17.5497ms

I:\Study\GO> .\goProgram.exe I:\data1.log "BUILD SUCCESS"
true
Execution time : 21.0613ms
```

data.log and data1.log is around 24MB.

does it build some kind of cache ? or some indexing it does around loaded file ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The operating system is caching data read from disk in memory for a while, so that repeated access to the same data will be faster. This is true for any kind of data, i.e. data used by the application but also the application and its libraries themselves. This is independent from the specific programs or programming language used.